# Mixing jQuery versions

Tags: jquery

I have a script i insert in to an HTML page when it is browsed.  My script uses the latest version of jQuery and i am running in to issues with people that already have an older version of jQuery declared on their page.  I have been re-assigning my jQuery object to my own varialbe to avoid the conflict, but i am wondering:  Is it possible to insert jQuery in to my own object without having to re-assign variable?  I mean going from something like:

```
var myJquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

to something like

```
myCustomObject.prototype.jQuery = //how do i populate this?

myCustomObject.jQuery.blahblah();
```

Im am wanting my version of jQuery to be a member of my javascript object.

Comment: Ugh! That is difficult. I would checking for the installed jQuery version, and fail gracefully if it's below what you need.

Comment: +1 what Pekka said. Running two copies of jQuery is a recipe for weird bug horror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're including jQuery core without modifying it, you can't do this...it overwrites the `window.jQuery` object itself, *that's* where the issues start.  Number one example: redeclaring `window.jQuery` and by proxy `window.jQuery.prototype` you erase all plugins in the page.

Check if `window.jQuery` exists before including it...otherwise you need to change jQuery core, in particular [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/core.js#L882):

```
return (window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery);
```

To something like:

```
return (myCustomObject.jQuery = jQuery);
```

In that context the `jQuery` on the end is a variable local the scope at that point, not yet screwing up much.

Comment: what do you mean "not yet screwing up much" :D  Will changing that line mess with any of the internal functions of jQuery?

Comment: @Mike_G - it is attaching event handlers and such for `document.ready`, so there's some activity going on...but I'm not sure what if any side-effects you'll have.  It's really not designed to do this, so you'll have to try your luck :) - It *shouldn't* mess anything up, since everything inside looks at that local variable.

Comment: Ok Nick, im messing with the core, and Ive renamed everything jQuery to sQuery, and jquery to squery in the my jQuery lib (literally a search and replace in notepad).  This seems to messing up a plugin that relies on a previously defined jQuery lib.  I would have thought that calling noConflict (sQuery.noConflict()) would work just as well, rather than editing the lines you suggest, but i was wrong. :)  Could you give a brief explanation why?

Comment: I would like to say "nevermind", as it works fine if i do not compress the script.